# Displaying ARKit nodes in relation to real objects

Tags: arkit

I am trying to draw a box that can help someone understand the dimensions of an item, but I keep having the issue that since I first need to recognize a plane when I put my physical item on top of the plane, my box gets drawn in front of the item.

Is it possible to somehow overcome this?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

[@John Scalo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45495756/3419541) is right, your problem is not having to first detect a plane, but it's that your render engine doesn't know that part of your green box frame is *occluded* (hidden) by a real-world object.

> *"…to somehow overcome this*"

Yes, and by doing so you might be "solving" your original problem—help someone understand the dimensions of an item.

(Depending on your choice of render engine, e.g. SceneKit) You can add an invisible 3D object that has the same dimensions as the real-world object; so the render engine will "know" that some parts of your box frame are behind this (for the user invisible) 3D object. Therefor, you can tell it not to draw those parts of your box frame, which will give the *illusion* (borrowing from Apple here) that your soda can has the box around it.

These workarounds are inaccurate, but maybe their accuracy is enough for the level of realism you are trying to achieve:

- Option 1: 1. After detecting the desk surface, place a semi-transparent 3D object over the soda can and then resize it (gestures/buttons your choice) until it's about the dimensions of the soda can. 2. Confirm that you're done, and just don't draw a texture on it at all just let it occlude the green box frame.
- Option 2: Hold your device near the edges of the soda can and add "enough" `ARAnchor`s to be able to create a "bounding shape" that (again) can be used to capture the real-word object and occlude that.
- Option 3: (intense, and perhaps the least accurate) Use your finger to "brush" over the object from various angles, and on each touch perform a hit test (hopefully the top/nearest hit is a part of your soda can) and build up a "bounding shape" that way.
- Option X: any combination of 1 - 2 - 3.

Good luck, there's lots of people trying to work around this device/ARKit limitation at them moment, so keep your eyes open for good ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're dealing with is called occlusion, and ARKit doesn't (currently?) include occlusion support. Maybe some day soon iPhones and iPads will begin to ship with LIDAR (or similar), in which case ARKit will be able to detect objects in the scene, making occlusion much easier.